# How to make user add object with required field?

Tags: javascript

I have an array with 50 users. So then i've a method add:(should accept object of user (field firstName is required), add it to array of users, (user id for new user should be generated programmatically and be unique))

```
const users = [{
  "id": 1,
  "first_name": "Abner",
  "last_name": "Glaisner",
  "gender": "Male",
  "language": "Tswana"
}, {
  //...
}]

class UserList {
  constructor(users) {
    this.users = users;
  }
  add(newUser) {
    if (typeof newUser === 'object' && typeof newUser !== null) {
      users.push(newUser);
      newUser.id = users.length;
      console.log(`Hello everyone i am ${newUser.first_name}`);
    } else {
      console.log('Please add object where first_name field is required!');
    }
  }
}
```

So what i need is when user writes

```
UserList.add({
  first_name: 'Jack',
  last_name: 'Nollan',
  //...
})
```

Make him to fill `first_name`.
Is it possible to do ?
And also i use newUser.id = user.length to generate user's id, is it possible to push it at the begining of object not to the end of it ?

Comment: Note that if you create a `class UserList` you're going to need to create an instance of `UserList` to call the function `add` on and can't call `UserList.add` directly unless you define it as `static`

Comment: A little suggestion for improvement: if `typeof newUser === 'object'` it can't be null anyway, which makes the second check obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

Answering your second question; You could achieve it by using the array spread operator you could do something like this:

```
users = [newUser, ...users];
```

Note that this overwrites the array every time you add something to it.
Another approach would be to `Array.reverse` it where you use it.

Comment: Why would you bother with so much overhead when [`unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) exists...?

Comment: @Oka I'd say because it seems much more intuitive this way rather than using the function you suggest. Moreover, this approach uses less characters, so if you're into code golfing expansion should be a better choice ;)

Comment: @AhmedBajra Actually `unshift` uses less characters since you don't have to overwrite the array but it manipulates it; so the equivalent statement would be `users.unshift(newUser)`. Therefore it's shorter _and_ more memory-friendly but you can't use it to use it to chain with ES6 functions like `filter` or `reduce` since it doesn't return the array.

Answer (score 1):

You should also check for new user's first and last name as they are required.
i.e: && newUser.first_name && newUser.last_name.

You can simply

```
if(newUser && typeOf newUser === "object" && newUser.first_name && newUser.last_name){
    //add to []
}else {
    //show message code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have an if block to check if it's a valid user, why not use it to check if `first_name` is set?

As for adding an object at the beginning of an array, you could use the expand operator for that. (`[newElement, ...array]`)

```
class UserList {
  constructor(users) {
    this.users = users;
  }
  add(newUser) {
    if (typeof newUser === 'object' && newUser.first_name) {
      users = [{id: users.length, ...newUser}, ...users];
      console.log(`Hello everyone i am ${newUser.first_name}`);
    } else {
      console.log('Please add object where first_name field is required!');
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

As Linschlager was quick to point out, you can even make it a one-liner by creating a new object from `id: users.length` and expanding the `newUser` object.

Comment: i mean if i add id to my new object which looks like obj = {'first_name: name'}
and then i add new key like obj.id = 10; It adds at the end of object, so it looks like obj = {first_name: 'name', id: 10}.
And what i need is obj = {id: 10, first_name: 'name'};

Comment: `newUser = { id: users.length+1, ...newUser };

users.push(newUser);`

Should do the trick then.

Comment: @Linschlager Yes, you're right, I'll edit my answer right away ;)